# Generating Business Layer for External Lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010, bcs

I have my custom database on backend and i have used BCS to bring in the information to SharePoint 2010. So far so good, but now I want to ideally use strongly types generated entities just like spmetal to work with the lists. Unfortunately, SPMETAl doesn't generate entities for external list.

What is the best way to deal with this situation?

How can I generate my Business Layer without spending much time on it as spmetal not a choice for me here.